# Upon sending an embed/message to a channel returns undefined

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, undefined

so i have this code i made for a reactionrole setup and i wanted to make it so it goes to "845711730809503744", but this returned undefined.
Full code:

```
client.channels.cache.get(channel => channel.id === "845711730809503744").send(roleEmbed)
```

```
                         ^          returns "Undefined"               ^
```

Does anybody know why and how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure the ID is correct. Then try to [`fetch`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ChannelManager?scrollTo=fetch) the channel. `fetch` obtains a channel from Discord, or the channel cache if it's already available.

```js
client.channels
  .fetch("845711730809503744")
  .then(channel => channel.send(roleEmbed))
  .catch(console.error)
```

Or you can use async/await:

```js
try {
  const channel = await client.channels.fetch("845711730809503744")
  channel.send(roleEmbed)
} catch(error) {
  console.error(error)
}
```

Comment: Hm, i tried the "fetch" way and that returns: `HTTPError [DiscordjsError]: Request to use token, but token was unavailable to the client.`, I think this is a problem with the "client" i think?

Comment: Not sure how your code looks like but this needs to be inside an event listener. The error message probably says that you try to make a HTTP request before the bot is logged in.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
const channel = client.channels.resolve('ID');
channel.send('ooh this is a message');
```